# Can 2 partitions of the same table have different indexes in PostgrSQL?

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, jsonb

I have a table called `CustomerData`, and within that I have 2 fields: `label`, and `data`. The `label` field is used to partition the table into smaller chunks. As one customer will never need to access another customer's data. The `data`  field is a JSONB field. Now, I want to apply indexes (such as GIN and others) on the `data` field, but different customers have different needs.

So my question is this:

**Can 2 partitions of the same table have different indexes in PostgrSQL?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE)

> Partitions may have their own indexes, constraints and default values, distinct from those of other partitions.

So the answer is: yes, two partitions can have different indexes.

Note that indexes created on the *partitioned table* (not on a single partition) will be created on all partitions automatically (at least since Postgres 11)

Comment: Doesn't the 2 statement contradict each other? 2 partitions can have different indexes, but indexes created will be replicated on all partitions automatically. So how would that work out?

Comment: @darkhorse: If you create the index on a partition only that partition will have that index. If you create the index on the partitioned table, all partitions will have that index

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Thanks!